In Genesis 11, during the geneology of Abraham from Shem, did the tower of Babel happen?
We are told in verse 10 (two years after the flood), Shem begat Arphaxad. Yet, verse 9 and earlier tells the story of the tower of Babel.

So the Lord scattered them from there over all the earth, and they
stopped building the city. 9 That is why it was called Babel—because
there the Lord confused the language of the whole world. From there
the Lord scattered them over the face of the whole earth.
This is the account of Shem’s family line:
Two years after the flood, when Shem was 100 years old, he became the
father of Arphaxad. (Genesis 11:8-10)


Genesis is not all in strict chronological order.  The account does not say exactly when the tower of Bable occurred so we do not know for certain.

Sorry I missed something in chapter 10 when the bible talks of Nimrod and Shinar

The Bible provides a clue about when the Tower of Babel event occurred.
Genesis 10:25 (NIV)

Two sons were born to Eber: One was named Peleg, because in his time the earth was divided; his brother was named Joktan.

The name Peleg (means division) is associated with Genesis 11:8-9, when the Lord scattered the people over the face of the whole earth:

8 So the Lord scattered them from there over all the earth, and they stopped building the city. 9 That is why it was called Babel—because there the Lord confused the language of the whole world. From there the Lord scattered them over the face of the whole earth. (NIV)


